# coef() vs. ranef() using glmer in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, mixed-model

I am running mixed effects regression in R, utilizing `glmer`, and am hoping someone can help clarify the difference between using `coef` and `ranef` on the results. Specifically, I have fixed effects $f_1,f_2,f_3$ and random effects $r_1,r_2,r_3.$ When I run `coef` I get certain coefficent values for each of the fixed and random effects. Additionally when I use the `ranef` function I get coefficients for my random effects. These two coefficients are not equal for each respective random effect $r_1,r_2,r_3.$ Why are these coefficients different and what information each coefficient tells us?

Comment: `coef` returns coefficients and `ranef` returns modes of random effects - what i not clear in it for you?

Comment: @Tim Why doesn't coef = ranef. Shouldn't the coefficient = mode of random effect = mean of random effect?

Comment: @Tim Then what information is being given to me when coef() returns a coefficient of a random effect?

Answer (score 5):

From [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf) documentation you can learn that

> `coef:` Computes the sum of the random and fixed effects coefficients
>   for each explanatory variable for each level of each grouping factor

and `ranef` is

> A generic function to extract the conditional modes of the random
>   effects from a fitted model object. For linear mixed models the
>   conditional modes of the random effects are also the conditional
>   means.

Comment: Hi Tim, can I have your opinion with this model ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570281/cross-mixed-model